# How define action in the case of different parameters? - asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I try define actions for diff params but its not working:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
  {
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      return  View();
    }

    public ActionResult Index(string name)
    {
      return new JsonResult();
    }

    public ActionResult Index(string lastname)
    {
      return new JsonResult();
    }

    public ActionResult Index(string name, string lastname)
    {
      return new JsonResult();
    }
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
      return new JsonResult();
    }
 }
```

but i get error:

**The current request for action 'Index' on controller type 'HomeController' is ambiguous between the following action methods ....**

Edit:

**If it not possible please suggest the best way to do it.**

Thanks,

Yosef

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`ActionNameAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionnameattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) attribute:

```
[ActionName("ActionName")]
```

Then, you'd have different names for each of the Action methods.

Comment: Thanks,Can yopu give some example for my the case that i write?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have overloaded action methods when they respond to same type of requests(GET, POST etc.). You should have a single public method with all the parameters you need. If the requests don't provide them they will be null and you can decide which overload you can use.

For this single public method you can take advantage of default model binding by defining a model.

```
public class IndexModel
{
    public string Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string LastName { get; set;}
}
```

Here's how your controller should look like:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(IndexModel model)
    {
        //do something here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These two can't live together because the compiler can't tell them apart.  Either rename them or delete one, or add an additional param.  This is true for all classes.

```
public ActionResult Index(string name) 
{ 
  return new JsonResult(); 
} 

public ActionResult Index(string lastname) 
{ 
  return new JsonResult(); 
}
```

Try using a single method with default parameters:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? id, string name = null, string lastName = null)
    {
        if (id.HasValue)
        {
            return new JsonResult();
        }

        if (name != null || lastName != null)
        {
            return new JsonResult();
        }

        return View();
    }
```

OR

```
    public ActionResult Index(int id = 0, string name = null, string lastName = null)
    {
        if (id > 0)
        {
            return new JsonResult();
        }

        if (name != null || lastName != null)
        {
            return new JsonResult();
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: all actions only get http (like web service)